# Access field value from other page in flutter, using bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc, rxdart

I want to access the token from other pages to make an authorized requests.

I am using rxdart, provider and streams.

I checked other questions and I do not think there are up to date answers about this matter.

Here I have a provider:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormProvider(
        child: MaterialApp(
        .... routing through other pages ...
```

My bloc:

```
  final _accessToken = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  ValueStream<String> get accessToken => _accessToken.stream;
  StreamSink get accessTokenSink => _accessToken.sink;
  accessTokenSink.add("123");
  print(accessToken.value); --> "123"
```

One of the pages from MaterialApp:

```
final accessToken = FormBloc().accessToken;
print(accessToken.value); --> ValueStream has no value. You should check ValueStream.hasValue before accessing ValueStream.value,
or use ValueStream.valueOrNull instead.
```

How can I make sure that I get that 123 value in every page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to take the value from the `stream` like `FormBloc().stream.value` or something like that. The normal scenario would be implementing a `StreamBuilder`. Take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/why-use-rxdart-and-how-we-can-use-with-bloc-pattern-in-flutter-a64ca2c7c52d) that might help

Comment: I have read this article, I am using StreamBuilders for widgets, i.e. fields and components and they do work fine, I am not sure why or how would I use StreamBuilder in my case?

Comment: You shouldn't use StreamBuilder in your case, I only said is the normal scenario. Did taking the value from the stream work?

Comment: I wish it had worked :( My code does something like `FormBloc()._accessToken.stream.value` but since I cannot access _ member of the class I defined  `accessToken = _accessToken.stream` It always returns value to be null